# Asking a name/address

Tags: objects

Which are correct?

> 1. He asked my name
> 2. He asked me my name
> 3. He asked for my name
> 4. He asked my address
> 5. He asked me my address
> 6. He asked for my address

Comment: All 6 are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them are correct but based on the context and place, people use one verses other. I guess, 1 and 4 are most used; 3 and 6 are least used.